# downloadUrl con archivo en local

Tags: php, javascript, api, google-maps

Estoy trabajando con la API  de Google Maps donde levanto las ubicaciones y descripciones desde el servidor al mapa. Para ello Tengo 4 archivos `db_connect.php` donde tengo mi funcion que conecta PHP con mi base de datos MySQL y `db_gmapi` que extiende de `db_connect.php` , conecta a la base de datos, levanta la info en esta y la guarda en un archivo XML al que he llamado `directions.xml` finalmente tengo mi `index.html` para la parte de cargar el mapa y mostrar los marcadores con las ubicaciones del archivo `directions.xml`.

El mapa carga, la BBDD conecta perfectamente, el archivo se genera... pero no muestra los marcadores debido que la función downloadUrl(url, callback) en mmi `index.html` exige justamente que el archivo `directions.xml` provenga de una "url" de archivo y yo estoy trabajando en localhost y el archivo está dentro de la carpeta raíz junto con `index.html`. Intente pegando la ruta del `directions.xml` y el nombre de archivo y no funcionó... ¿Como puedo resolver?

Código `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
```

```
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

```
<script>
  var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
      label: 'A'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
      zoom: 12
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // a continuación el problema
      downloadUrl('//directions.xml', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MI-API-KEY]&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi con `downloadUrl('http://localhost/carpetaraiz/directions.xml', function(data)`